# Upgraded to .NET Core 3.1 and receiving an error in a LINQ query related to using .FirstOrDefault()

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an Entity Framework controller that has been using the method below successfully.  However I recently updated my project to use .NET Core 3.1 and it must've broken something.

I am now getting this error:

> FirstOrDefault()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

I did some research, and some people say not to use `GroupBy` extension which I do in the query below. I tried to take it out, but that just generates more errors.

I also went to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval):

But I couldn't figure out how to fix my complex query below.

Honestly, I'm not sure why it's failing or how to properly fix it.

Does anyone see anything wrong?

Thanks!

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetStarChemicalData(string starID)
        {
            var starChemicalData = await (from starlist in _context.StarList
                                          join ql in _context.ChemicalList on starlist.ChemicalId equals ql.ChemicalId into stars
                                          from chemicallist in stars.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          join qc in _context.ChemicalAtoms on chemicallist.ChemicalId equals qc.ChemicalId into chemicals
                                          from chemicalatoms in chemicals.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          join nk in _context.StarLinks on chemicalatoms.AtomId equals nk.AtomId into links
                                          from starlinks in links.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          where starlist.StarId == starID
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              StarId = starlist.StarId,
                                              StarType = starlist.StarType,
                                              StarTitle = starlist.StarTitle,
                                              ChemicalId = starlist.ChemicalId,
                                              AtomId = (Guid?)chemicalatoms.AtomId,
                                              OrderId = chemicalatoms.OrderId,
                                              ChemicalText = chemicallist.ChemicalText,
                                              AtomText = chemicalatoms.AtomText,
                                              Wavelength = chemicalatoms.Wavelength,
                                              isRedShifted = (starlinks.AtomId != null && starlist.StarType == 1) ? 1
                                              : (starlinks.AtomId == null && starlist.StarType == 1) ? 0
                                              : (int?)null
                                          })
                                              .GroupBy(x => x.StarId)
                                              .Select(g => new
                                              {
                                                  StarId = g.FirstOrDefault().StarId,
                                                  StarType = g.FirstOrDefault().StarType,
                                                  StarTitle = g.FirstOrDefault().StarTitle,
                                                  ChemicalId = g.FirstOrDefault().ChemicalId,
                                                  ChemicalText = g.FirstOrDefault().ChemicalText,
                                                  ChemicalAtoms = (g.FirstOrDefault().AtomId != null ? g.Select(x => new
                                                  {
                                                      AtomId = x.AtomId,
                                                      OrderId = x.OrderId,
                                                      AtomText = x.AtomText,
                                                      Feedback = x.Wavelength,
                                                      IsCorrect = x.isRedShifted
                                                  }) : null)
                                              }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            return starChemicalData;
```

ERROR AFTER DEBUGGING:

```
.Select(x => new { 
    AtomId = x.AtomId, 
    OrderId = x.OrderId, 
    AtomText = x.AtomText, 
    Feedback = x.Wavelength, 
    IsCorrect = x.isRedShifted
 })' could not be translated.
```

Comment: Rewrite the query using navigation properties. Then most likely you'll find that it doesn't need the problematic `GroupBy`.  Current query look complex because it uses SQL approach  translated to LINQ, while it should be other way around. Looking at the current query I would expect something simple as `_context.StarList.Select(sl => new { sl.StarId/, * other sl properties ...*/, ChemicalAtoms = sl.ChemicalAtoms.Select(ca => new {  ca.AtomId/, * other ca properties ...*/ }) })`

Comment: I went to the Microsoft docs to try and figure out what navigation properties are.  So would they just be classes that are not in the database?  Also, my GroupBy uses an id (StarId).  That Id is in the database.  So I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Comment: @IvanStoev I spent some time trying to rewrite the query as use suggested.  However ChemicalAtoms is not part of StartList.  ChemicalAtoms comes from a join. So I can't do as you suggested; which is: sl.ChemicalAtoms.Select(...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have alot of FirstOrDefault (s) calls.

To code them "safely", you can try this:

```
.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty
```

or

```
.FirstOrDefault() ?? 0
```

..
the above is a short hand version of this: (null check + ? ternary operator) (again, this is a "safe" way to code it)

```
StarId = null == g.FirstOrDefault() ? 0 : g.FirstOrDefault().StarId,
StarType = null == g.FirstOrDefault() ? string.Empty : g.FirstOrDefault().StarType,
StarTitle = null == g.FirstOrDefault() ? string.Empty : g.FirstOrDefault().StarTitle,
```

..

But better to debug, to figure out what is wrong

Change ALL OF these (temporarilty) to "" and 0

I'm listing 3 of them, but you should change all of them

instead of this:

```
StarId = g.FirstOrDefault().StarId,
StarType = g.FirstOrDefault().StarType,
StarTitle = g.FirstOrDefault().StarTitle,
```

use (temporarily) this:

```
   StarId = 0,
   StarType = "",
    StarTitle = "",
```

(again do ALL of them)

and one-by-one, replace them back

```
    StarId = g.FirstOrDefault().StarId,
   StarType = "",
    StarTitle = "",
```

to find the "culprit".

Here is some pseudo code.......that you can try to use the intermediate step of IQueryable.  Its pseduo code, you'll have to tweak.

IQueryable is a way to "slowly build up the query" instead of writing a single super query.......and helps with debugging.  Eventually, you will comment out (or delete) ...       tempDebuggingCollection ........ but it can help get you to where you want to go.

```
public async Task<ActionResult<object>> GetStarChemicalData(string starID)
        {
            IQueryable<YourObjectHere> starChemicalDataQueryable = await (from starlist in _context.StarList
                                          join ql in _context.ChemicalList on starlist.ChemicalId equals ql.ChemicalId into stars
                                          from chemicallist in stars.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          join qc in _context.ChemicalAtoms on chemicallist.ChemicalId equals qc.ChemicalId into chemicals
                                          from chemicalatoms in chemicals.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          join nk in _context.StarLinks on chemicalatoms.AtomId equals nk.AtomId into links
                                          from starlinks in links.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          where starlist.StarId == starID;
                                    
            ICollection<YourObjectHere> tempDebuggingCollection = starChemicalDataQueryable.ToListAsync(CancellationToken.None);
                                    
                    
            var starChemicalData = starChemicalDataQueryable
                                        select new
                                          {
                                              StarId = starlist.StarId,
                                              StarType = starlist.StarType,
                                              StarTitle = starlist.StarTitle,
                                              ChemicalId = starlist.ChemicalId,
                                              AtomId = (Guid?)chemicalatoms.AtomId,
                                              OrderId = chemicalatoms.OrderId,
                                              ChemicalText = chemicallist.ChemicalText,
                                              AtomText = chemicalatoms.AtomText,
                                              Wavelength = chemicalatoms.Wavelength,
                                              isRedShifted = (starlinks.AtomId != null && starlist.StarType == 1) ? 1
                                              : (starlinks.AtomId == null && starlist.StarType == 1) ? 0
                                              : (int?)null
                                          })
                                              .GroupBy(x => x.StarId)
                                              .Select(g => new
                                              {
                                                  StarId = g.FirstOrDefault().StarId,
                                                  StarType = g.FirstOrDefault().StarType,
                                                  StarTitle = g.FirstOrDefault().StarTitle,
                                                  ChemicalId = g.FirstOrDefault().ChemicalId,
                                                  ChemicalText = g.FirstOrDefault().ChemicalText,
                                                  ChemicalAtoms = (g.FirstOrDefault().AtomId != null ? g.Select(x => new
                                                  {
                                                      AtomId = x.AtomId,
                                                      OrderId = x.OrderId,
                                                      AtomText = x.AtomText,
                                                      Feedback = x.Wavelength,
                                                      IsCorrect = x.isRedShifted
                                                  }) : null)
                                              }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();                                       
  

            return starChemicalData;
```

............

AGain, same safe checks:

```
               ChemicalAtoms = (g.FirstOrDefault().AtomId != null ? g.Select(x => new
                                              {
                                                  AtomId = x.AtomId,
                                                  OrderId = x.OrderId,
                                                  AtomText = x.AtomText,
                                                  Feedback = x.Wavelength,
                                                  IsCorrect = x.isRedShifted
                                              }) : null)
```

You are not safely checking for g.FirstOrDefault() ....

something like this:

```
         ChemicalAtoms = null == g.FirstOrDefault() ? null : (g.FirstOrDefault().AtomId != null ? g.Select(x => new
                                              {
                                                  AtomId = x.AtomId,
                                                  OrderId = x.OrderId,
                                                  AtomText = x.AtomText,
                                                  Feedback = x.Wavelength,
                                                  IsCorrect = x.isRedShifted
                                              }) : null)
```

Comment: Thanks, so you think one of the values is not being set correctly and causing the error?

Comment: I think.... FirstOrDefault is bringing back a null, and when you code "g.FirstOrDefault().StarId" .. it ~~assumes~~ it is not null, and the property call (.StarId) fails with the error you are getting.        if you don't do the "safe", then you should write these g.First().StarId, .. which means you are very very certain the First one exists.

Comment: impressed with this answer just here to pat u on the back

Comment: Wow thanks...So I did add the debugging test values and got a different error..which I added to the end of my question above.  Thanks!

Comment: I updated the my answer.  But it is the same "safe check FirstOrDefault" mentality.  Keep looking for "holes" where you assume something is not null.    You (like me and everyone else) and your time to debug this is just adding to this !!  :)         https://medium.com/@hinchman_amanda/null-pointer-references-the-billion-dollar-mistake-1e616534d485

Comment: Apparently this answer is coming from general programming background. The actual issue though has nothing in common with safety and nulls - these are handled naturally in SQL *when* the query gets translated successfully, which does nit happen with this particular type of LINQ queries - `GrouBy` with result other than simple key / aggregates, as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby).